# Backup-SqlDatabase with specific Windows Authentifiation

Tags: powershell, backup-sqldatabase

I try to use the powershell command *Backup-SqlDatabase* with a specific windows authentication (not the current)

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $instanceName -Database $databaseName -BackupAction Database -Credential $credential -BackupFile $backupFilePath
```

With *-Credential*, it only supports SQL authentication

Without it uses the current windows user authentication

Comment: I tried to use a new Powershell session (New-PSSession) with the specific windows authentification but in this case I lose the context of my powershell library "SqlServer": ObjectNotFound:
The 'Backup-SqlDatabase' command was found in the 'SQLPS' module, but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module SQLPS'.

Comment: I would take a look at DBAtools for powershell, extremely useful when working with SQL server. They have a backup function that should work with active directory login: https://docs.dbatools.io/Backup-DbaDatabase